# hide child element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide "arrow_o" on click of "thead" but it is not working. Does jquerys "children" not work in tables?

html

```
<thead class="thead">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div class="arrow_o"></div>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thead').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.arrow_o').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: If you're having trouble with a particular jQuery method, a good place to start is the [doco for that method](http://api.jquery.com/children/)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

So this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thead').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.arrow_o').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Also, check out Vega's answer, $(selector, this) is an elegant, if a little less readable way to get child elements.

Comment: @Kato Setting the context in jQuery essentially translated internally within jQuery to using the `.find()` method on the specific context so this is still the best solution as it is more readable :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `$('.arrow_o', this).hide();` which basically sets the context where the `arrow_o` should be located.

**Full Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thead').click(function() {
     $('.arrow_o', this).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

[jQuery children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead.